# How can rvalue reference bind to lvalue during function call

Tags: c++, c++11, move

AFAI understand, rvalue reference cannot bind to lvalue. But going through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward I see an example code section has:

```
template<class T, class U>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique1(U&& u)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(u)));
}
```

which is called using:

```
int i = 1;
auto p2 = make_unique1<A>(i); // lvalue
```

Why/how does this work? `i` being lvalue shouldn't bind to `U&&` unless we explicitly call `std::move(i)`, right? Or I am missing something here.

Comment: Look up *forwarding references*. The compiler deduces `U` to `int &`, which turns `U &&` into `int &` as well.

Comment: `U&& u` is not an RValue reference but a Universal Reference. (`U` is a template type parameter.) That makes _the_ difference.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why does the compiler deduce `U` to `int &` and not `int` ?

Comment: @Akash Because that's what the deduction rules are. Read about forwarding references.

Comment: The rules for template argument deduction, and for reference collapsing, are carefully specified precisely so as to make perfect forwarding work.